# How are orthogonal groups over $\mathbb{R}$ parameterized by symmetric bilinear forms?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$.  Suppose $G$ is given an $\mathbb{R}$-structure, i.e. an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $A_0$ such that $A = \mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} A_0$, where $A$ is the coordinate ring of $G$.  Then the Galois group $\Gamma = \textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ acts as a group of ring automorphisms $A$ as $\sigma.(\lambda \otimes a) = \sigma(\lambda) \otimes a$, which induces an action of $\Gamma$ on $\textrm{Spm } A = G$.

Then $\Gamma$ further acts on $\textrm{Aut}(G)$, the group of algebraic group automorphisms of $G$, as $\gamma.\phi(x) = \gamma^{-1}.\phi(\gamma.x)$

The isomorphism classes of $\mathbb{R}$-structures on $G$ form a pointed set, the distinguished element corresponding to class of $A_0$.  This pointed set is isomorphic to $H^1(\Gamma, \textrm{Aut}(G))$, the set of equivalence classes of one-cocycles, i.e. functions $c: \Gamma \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(G)$ for which $c(\gamma_1\gamma_2) = c(\gamma_1) \circ \gamma_1.(c(\gamma_2))$ for all $\gamma_i \in \Gamma$.

If $M$ is a symmetric invertible real matrix, one can define $\textrm{O}_n(\mathbb{C}) = \{ x \in \textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) : x^t Mx = M \}$.  As an algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$, $O_n(\mathbb{C})$ does not depend on the choice of $M$ up to isomorphism.  But over $\mathbb{R}$, different choice of $M$ may yield different groups.

Is there is a connection between the set $H^1(\Gamma, \textrm{Aut}(G))$ and classes of invertible symmetric matrices $M$?  (two matrices $M_1, M_2$ being equivalent if there exists an $x \in \textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $x^tM_1x = M_2$)

Comment: Over an arbitrary field $K$ of characteristic zero, and two nondegenerate quadratic form $q,q'$ in dimension $n\ge 2$, the groups $SO(q)$ and $SO(q')$ are $K$-isomorphic iff $q$ and $q'$ are equivalent up to rescaling: see last paragraph of my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/200353/when-do-two-non-degenerate-quadratic-forms-give-rise-to-isomorphic-lie-algebras/200947#200947

Answer (score 5):

For $\mathit{SO}_n$ instead of $\mathit{O}_n$, and for real semisimple groups in general, your question is quite clearly addressed by the text ["Galois Cohomology of Real Groups" by Jeffrey Adams](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7917) (see, in particular, the tables given at the end).  See also [these slides](https://www.birs.ca/workshops/2015/15w5016/files/Borovoi.pdf) by Mikhail Borovoi.  This should at least clarify a number of things about Galois cohomology of real algebraic groups.

The classes of rank $n$ real quadratic forms (i.e., equivalence classes of symmetric matrices) are classified by $H^1(\mathbb{R},\mathit{O}_n)$, which has cardinality $n+1$ given by Sylvester's law of inertia (the signature of the quadratic form).  The real forms of $\mathit{O}_n$ are, as you remark, classified by $H^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathrm{Aut}(\mathit{O}_n))$.  Now we have an inner automorphism map $\mathit{O}_n \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathit{O}_n)$ whose kernel has order $2$ and whose image has index $1$ or $2$ (the latter if $n$ is even $\geq 4$, I hope I got this right: [see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235758/automorphism-group-of-real-orthogonal-lie-groups)).  From Galois cohomology we get a map $H^1(\mathbb{R},\mathit{O}_n) \to H^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathrm{Aut}(\mathit{O}_n))$ (of pointed sets) which, concretely, maps a quadratic form to the orthogonal group it defines, which factors through $H^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathrm{Inn}(\mathit{O}_n))$ where $\mathrm{Inn}(\mathit{O}_n) = \mathit{O}_n/\{\pm1\}$.  So certainly there "is a connection".  But it is not quite a bijection.

For $n$ odd, $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathit{O}_n) = \mathrm{Inn}(\mathit{O}_n) = \mathit{SO}_n$, the set $H^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathit{SO}_n)$ has cardinality $\frac{n+1}{2}$ (see Adams's paper mentioned above), and the map $H^1(\mathbb{R},\mathit{O}_n) \to H^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathrm{Aut}(\mathit{O}_n))$ you were asking about is surjective and two-to-one, mapping two opposite signatures $(p,q)$ and $(q,p)$ to the same real form $\mathit{O}_{p,q}$.  For $n$ even, things are messier, and you should note the existence of the group $\mathit{O}^*_n$ (of maps preserving a skew-hermitian quaternionic form of quaternionic rank $n/2$; see, e.g., Onishchik & Sulanke, *Projective and Cayley-Klein Geometries*, Springer 2006, [§2.1.6](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xvlt-YM07WwC&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143)) which is a real form of $\mathit{O}_n$ that does not come from a real quadratic form; I *think* $H^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathrm{Aut}(\mathit{O}_n))$ has cardinality exactly $\frac{n}{2}+1$ and that the map $H^1(\mathbb{R},\mathit{O}_n) \to H^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathrm{Aut}(\mathit{O}_n))$ is two-to-one everywhere except over $\mathit{O}_{k,k}$ where $k=n/2$ and except that $\mathit{O}^*_n$ is not in its image, but I am not sure.

Comment: "see here" does not open!

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Fixed! (I don't know how I managed to delete the 'e' in `.net`)